# How do I prove that there doesn't exist a set whose power set is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't even know where to begin on this one.

Let $A$ be a countable set. In other words, $|A| = |\mathbb{N}|$. I'm trying to prove that there doesn't exist an $x$ such that $\mathcal{P}x = A$.

Maybe a proof by contradiction? Suppose there was a set $x$ whose power set was countable ...

Comment: It was asked already. You can see that question at [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/201923/53976).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's possibly helpful to know the answer to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071516/how-do-i-prove-that-for-any-set-a-a-mathbbn-implies-that-a-is-fi). (Thanks for mentioning that question's existence in a comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

- Can the power set of a finite set be infinite?
- Is the power set of a countably infinite set countable? In particular, is $\wp(\Bbb N)$ countable?

Comment: I think he is struggling with the second part. Nice to see you btw Brian. :). Or read your text,more than see you.

Comment: Yes, if I show that $x$ countable implies $\mathcal{P}x$ uncountable, then I am done ... hmmm isn't this Cantor's Theorem or something

Comment: @Jorge: You could be right. But I’ll be here for a while to answer further questions. (Yes, I was away for quite a while there.)

Comment: @Vincent: It is indeed [Cantor’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: $\mathcal{P}x \neq x$ for all $x$

Comment: Okay, I thought this was a way harder question than it was ... thanks again!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the fact that we ought to prove that no infinite set is smaller than $\mathbb N$ before this works.

Comment: @Meelo I did that in a previous question I asked

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stronger fact (provable without the axiom of choice): If $\mathbb N$ injects into $\mathcal P(A)$, then in fact $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ injects into $\mathcal P(A)$. This is an elegant result of Kuratowski, and appears as Théorème B in

> Alfred Tarski. [*Sur les ensembles finis*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm6/fm619.pdf), Fund. Math. 6 (1924), 45–95.

(Clearly, if $\mathcal P(A)$ is infinite, then so is $A$. The stronger fact is fairly easy if one assumes that $\mathbb N$ injects into $A$. But it is consistent with the axioms of set theory without choice that there are infinite sets into which $\mathbb N$ does not inject. Even more, it is consistent that there are infinite sets $A$ such that $\mathbb N$ does not inject into $\mathcal P(A)$, so the assumption cannot be weakened.)

The outline of the proof is simple: If $\mathbb N$ injects into $\mathcal P(A)$, then there is a surjection $g$ from $A$ onto $\mathbb N$. But then we have an injection $f$ from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ into $\mathcal P(A)$, given by $f(X)=\{a\in A\mid g(a)\in X\}$. The difficult step is to produce the surjection $g$.

I wrote the details of this argument in my [blog](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/dedekind-infinite-power-sets).

Comment: Is that the same Tarski from the sphere mapping to two spheres?

Comment: Yes, the same. :-)